# PTIJ: The Hulk & the principle of "כל דאלים גבר" (ie "whoever is stronger prevails")

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

When there are two people arguing over an object or piece of land and neither of them has a stronger proof than the other’s, the gemara in
[Bava Basra 34a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.34b.1-2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) teaches us about the principle of:

> **כל דאלים גבר**
>
> "whoever is stronger prevails"

[Rashbam](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.34b.2?lang=bi&p2=Rashbam_on_Bava_Batra.34b.2.2&lang2=bi) (ad. loc.) suggests this applies in any case where two people argue and neither has convincing proof.

**Enter The Hulk**

1) If you look closely at the concept the word "**גבר**" ie "**man**" is used. Is the The Hulk considered a man?
בּשלמא [Bruce Banner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Banner_(Marvel_Cinematic_Universe)), he's legitimately a person. אלא is [The Hulk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulk) still considered a "man" or is it a brand new non-human entity, and thus "כל דאלים גבר" wouldn't apply in this case?
(regardless, you **WON'T** like him angry)

2) Even if you say The Hulk still has a *shem* "man"- is it fair to have The Hulk show up in a כל דאלים גבר dispute? Assumption is two regular people are fighting- NOT someone like The Hulk!

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that.

אל תקרא אלים אלא אילם

Not violent but mute. If you learn the topic carefully, you can note that Hulk grunts but doesn't pronounces words. So he is a man. But 
אם אפשר לקיים את שניהם בלי סתירה, יש אם למקרא ואם למסורת.

We need to learn from Alim, and from Ilem.

So the principle of kol dealim gvar is applicable for Hulk.

See in Shut Harosh (and Rosh Chezkat Habatim siman 22), quoted in Bach, that who is right is more bitter. So, since Hulk suffers injustices, he is stronger, despite his sick complexion.

Comment: Um... Hulk *does* talk. In the comics, there are times that he talks like a child, and times that he has Banner’s full intellect and mental capabilities (Professor Hulk and Doc Green storylines). In the MCU, he’s been shown to talk to a certain degree since his introduction. So you don’t need to appeal to יש אם למקרא ויש אם למסורת to reach this conclusion.

Comment: Tora dhebeal pe mipi hashmua

Answer (score 0):

Psalms 29:

> הבו לה׳ בני אלים
>
> Ascribe to the Lord, to the sons of the stronger ones